# Adding post meta by URL in wp-admin

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a script that order Wordpress posts by `custom field` and I would like to have a link that add's a custom field by clicking on it.

**Like this (or so):** `<a href="/wp-admin/post.php?action=add_post_meta&my_meta_key&my_meta_value&post=1500&_wpnonce=...`

**My script uses:**

```
$path = preg_replace('/wp-content.*$/','',__DIR__);
include($path.'wp-load.php');
global $wpdb;
```

Is this possble?

Comment: @demo7up I want to **add** `custom fields`, **not** `get_post_meta`

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/158765/add-custom-field-to-post-with-some-part-of-url-as-value Sorry I copied the wrong link this was the one I wanted to share!

Comment: @demo7up not quite that... What I need is an admin URL that add's a custom field to a `$post->ID`

Something like my example above (`<a href="/wp-admin/post.php?action=add_post_meta&my_meta_key&my_meta_value&post=1500&_wpnonce=...`)
What this does is compare an URL and if it matches: `add_post_meta`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you script something like this:

```php
if( current_user_can('manage_options')) {       
    // Check and get any post meta
    $post_meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'post_meta', true );

    if (!empty($post_meta)){
        add_post_meta($post->ID, 'new_meta', 1, true);
    } 
}
```

Now you can place this on your `single.php`, and... et voilà!

When you open the post, the new meta will be added.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to look for any meta in post. You can simply do this on your `single.php`:

```
  if( current_user_can('manage_options')) {
   add_post_meta($post->ID, 'new_meta', 1, true);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also add this on `functions.php`

```
add_action('insert_post_meta', 'adding_new_custom_field');
function adding_new_custom_field ($post_id)
{
    if ( $_POST['post_type'] == 'post' ) {
        add_post_meta($post_id, 'new_meta_key_name', 'new meta value', true);
    }
    return true;
}
```